# automapper convert typeof object to enum

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to use Automapper to specify a column using ForMember(?) to be an enum value of the type of the object that is being mapped.

For example I have

```
class base
class A : base
class B : base

enum objTypeEnum
{
    istypebase,
    istypea,
    istypeb
}
```

base constains a property

```
objTypeEnum TypeEnum;
```

During the mapping I want to resolve the type of the object being mapped to the TypeEnum property:

.ForMember(dest => dest.TypeEnum, opt => opt.MapFrom())

Can't figure out the resolver, and how to use it. Using the resolver I created, the MapFrom complains that it needs a source definition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can `ForMember` method and you define an expression where the argument is the `source`. So, use the source to provide what you want to set on the `destination` property.

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.TypeEnum, 
           option => option.MapFrom(source => {
                // some logic here based on source object to convert it to enum
                // for sample:
                if (source.Prop == null)
                    return TypeEnum.A;
                else
                    return TypeEnum.B;
           }))
```